# Conversion from \xff to 0xff

Tags: python, binary, hex, binary-data

I'm reading a binary input register from an ADC, the input that im getting is like this: 
`data = '\xff\xff\xff\xff' , data[0] = '\xff'` I have to translate that data in to 2's complement numbers fix8_7 (fixed binary point in the 7th bit from LSB), i'm using this functions in order to do it:

```
def twos_comp(val, bits):
    # Compute the 2's compliment of int value val
    if( (val&(1<<(bits-1))) != 0 ):
        val = val - (1<<bits)
    return val

def fix8_7(val):
    # Take a signed int of 8 bit an pass it to fix8_7 (fixed binary point in 7th LSB)
    val = val / 128.0
    return val
```

The way to use them is:

```
val1 = twos_comp(int('0xff',16),len(val))
fix8_7(val1)
```

But I'm getting an error because I need the input to be an hex value like 0xff or ff no \xff, how can I fix this??

Comment: `ord('\xff') == 0xff`... in other words, convert your byte string to a list of 8-bit values: `datavalues = [ord(x) for x in datastring]`.

Comment: or drive your processing loop with `map(ord,datastring)` or `itertools.imap(ord,datastring)`.

Comment: I tried ord('\xff') but that gives me 255 and i need that two's complement so that value is not correct. thnks

Comment: err... 255 == 0xff ???  int('0xff') == 255 ??? 0xff is hexedecimal notation for decimal 255, which are the **same** value.

Comment: its two's complement.. , 0xff with 8 bits its -1 not 255

Comment: @maverick88 Python does arbitrary precision arithmetic. But you are talking about 8 bit arithmetic.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yeah im aware of that, but those functions that i posted work fine with 8 bit aritmetic, I just need to translate the input data from '\xff' to '0xff'. thnks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to change `\xff` to `0xff`, you can simply use `ord` and `hex` functions like this

```
data = '\xff\xff\xff\xff'
data = map(hex, map(ord, data))
print data
# ['0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `twos_comp(val, bits)` function expects arguments to be integers. You could get integers directly without converting input into `'0xff'` strings first using [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
>>> data = '\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> b = bytearray(data)
>>> b[0] == 0xff
True
```